# base_url working in main controller but not in sub controller/views

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I've been working with CodeIgniter for a while now and I already had my base_url working. I recently moved to CentOS 7 and had to set my server up all over again. It was a pretty smooth transition, but I've been tinkering around with some of the modules and such. Long story short, my base_url is no longer working and I cannot figure out why.

base_url is currently set to http://IP/Directory/

index is set to ' '

url helper is loaded

.htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

httpd has been configured. phpd has been configured. mysqld has been configured. The last thing I did before I noticed that it broke was I set selinux to permissive.

To elaborate on how it is broken-- When at the actual base_url, everything is working perfectly. When I go into a subdirectory (another controller/view) it no longer recognizes the base_url. I found that if I add a "../" it works for some strange reason in that subdirectory, but it breaks the main controller. It's acting as if the base_url is equal to the current directory level rather than the actual base_url that I specified.

Edit: Directory Layout -

```
www > 
     html > 
            websitefolder > 
                            css|img|font|codeigniterfolders
```

Also forgot to mention another thing I did before it broke was moved the css, img, and font folder to assets subdirectory, but I've moved them back to base_url root.

Comment: did you autoload url helper?

Comment: Yes. I said that in my initial question. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please add your directory layout to you question.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 Added directory layout.

Comment: @WarMachine how your Base_url look like

Comment: @Abdulla $config['base_url'] = http://127.0.0.1/websitefolder/

Comment: @WarMachine just remove it and keep empty. it will works

Comment: @WarMachine what is you hosted site??

Comment: @Abdulla now I'm getting A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: strpos(): Empty needle Filename: helpers/form_helper.php Line Number: 68

Comment: where you use starpos???

Comment: Says right there in the comment... helpers/form_helper.php. Not something I've messed with, tbh. Oh, and I'm not hosting this publicly yet. It's on my personal test bed.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "no longer recognizes the base_url"?

Comment: @Narf Did you only read the title? I answered that in the main post. Thanks.

Comment: @WarMachine What you've given as an answer to that question seems vague, which is why I'm asking *exactly* what you mean. Preferrably with examples, like you've done with the .htaccess file (which is irrelevant btw).

Comment: And also, if you're getting a notice about `strpos()` on line 68 of the form helper ... that means you're using a really, really old version of CI - 2.2.0 at best. And CI 2.x is no longer supported anymore, so you should upgrade ASAP - that may even fix whatever issue you're having, as you'll get hundreds of bugfixes with CI3.

Comment: @Narf I will upgrade as soon as I am able to. As for being vague with the the problem description, I do apologize. Also, I did my fair share of research before deciding to post, which is why I added the .htaccess stuff. If I'm able to correct the issue by updating, I will be sure to post here. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up- I resolved my issue by changing the way I use the base_url to  instead of what I initially learned what to use. Was still having the issue in CI 3.